# How to add originalevent to a programmatically triggered event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events

Here I have added a code and it is working as expected, but I would like to have the originalevent added to this since I want to do a trigger programmatically to check the "event.originalEvent" attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var e = jQuery.Event( "keypress", { which: 32, keyCode: 32 } );
    $("#campaign_message_write textarea#campaign_body").keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        console.log(e)
      } else {
        console.log(e)
      }
    })
$("#campaign_message_write textarea#campaign_body").trigger(e);
});
```

Screenshot of the console.log(e) is attached when it is triggered programatically.
[image]

Screenshot of the console.log(e) attached when the event is triggered manually using keyboard
[image]

Note: I want to programmatically add the "originalevent" even through the trigger is made through the program. If there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Your `e` *inside* the `keypress(function(e)` is not the same variable as the one outside.  How do you trigger programmatically?  (imgs are blocked where I am, so apologies if it's shown on there, it's not shown in the question code.)

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry I have missed to add the trigger event to the question. Now you can check that. It is the same event "e"

Comment: Then which is the "original event"?  The doc.ready event?

Comment: If I am typing anything that is only considered as the "original event" and the one which I am triggering using the trigger is not considered as "origin event"

Comment: Ah you want to "add originalevent" - sorry, misread it as "want to add *the* originalevent"

Comment: Yes I wanted to add originalevent if the trigger is happened programmatically also

Comment: TBH, isn't that the whole point of knowing that it's trusted?  If you can just "claim" to be trusted or "claim" to be a bona-fide keypress event then there's no point in having that level of security.  Assuming it's *your* code, then don't check for isTrusted, or do check for some other parameter you pass in.  If you're trying to hack someone else's page then that's a different issue and you'll be better off running the code for the keypress directly (or by replicating it)

Comment: Yes I understand about the explanation and sorry about the confusion again. It is not checking for the isTrusted. I wanted to check for "e.originalEvent"

Comment: Please include code/data/errors as text, not as a picture of text. Also, there is no `originalEvent` when you trigger the event programmatically, but if you want to go down that rabbit hole, you are constructing the event already in `var e = jQuery.Event( "keypress", { which: 32, keyCode: 32 } );` just add `originalEvent` to that second argument. You'll have to decide what object to put there, because nothing makes sense, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: *because nothing makes sense* - hence my question earlier of what do you think the `originalEvent` should be?  Normally an example of this would be where you have an on-screen keyboard and you `click` a letter then trigger/raise a `keypress` event and pass in the *original event* - ie the click event.   Here there isn't an "original" even being fired other than doc.ready, which seems somewhat inappropriate.